# How do i query splunk for latest and earliest time based on epoch time rather than human readable time?

Tags: timestamp, epoch, splunk

I have a field called as "impact_time" which has human readable dates in it. Now i want to query splunk for a range of impact_time. The only problem is that the earliest and latest time that i have is in epoch format. How do i make splunk query based on the epoch time range that i am passing?

Answer (score 0):

as you need is the data within a range of a field, named impact_time,
  try directly using it in a search.

```
 index=...
 | search impact_time>[specific time to start] AND impact_time<[specific time to end] | ...
```

assuming, you need events between some particular range of data in a field, which happens to be time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert impact_time from human readable to epoch e.g.

```
... | eval impact_time_epoch=strptime(impact_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)
```

Then you can use the where command to filter for the range you need

E.g.

```
... | where impact_time_epoch >= EARLIEST impact_time_epoch <= LATEST
```